# NoMethodError while using breadcrumbs_on_rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to use gem breadcrumbs_on_rails.

I want to use the name attribute of my vehicle model in the current breadcrumbs element, so I'm using a Symbol as Breadcrumb Element, which calls the corresponding method defined in the same context and sets the Element attribute to the returned value (as per [gem documentation](https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails)).

```
#vehicles_controller.rb
  def show
    @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    add_breadcrumb "home", :root_path
    add_breadcrumb "user profile", :current_user
    add_breadcrumb :set_vehicle_name, :user_vehicle_path
  end

  ...

  private

    #return vehicle name for breadcrumb
    def set_vehicle_name
      @vehicle.name
    end
```

My view is as follow:

```
#vehicles/show.html..erb
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <%= render_breadcrumbs :separator => " / " %>
</ol>
```

When I run the server and access the page I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Vehicles#show
undefined method `set_vehicle_name' for #<#<Class:0x007f40edd52958>:0x007f40f18fe790>
```

Can you tell me what's causing this error? thanks

Comment: `set_vehicle_name` is private method. Make it `protected` or `public`.

Comment: making it public does not change things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it working appending `helper_method :set_vehicle_name` after the private method definition, as specified in [this](https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails/issues/21#issuecomment-21139232) post.

> The gem uses the context of an ActionView::Base ([breadcrumbs.rb#L25](https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails/blob/master/lib/breadcrumbs_on_rails/breadcrumbs.rb#L25))
>   to evaluate any methods ([breadcrumbs.rb#L50](https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails/blob/master/lib/breadcrumbs_on_rails/breadcrumbs.rb#L50)). It's complaining because
>   you haven't made your method in your controller available to the view.
>
> Use helper_method to make it available to your views and it will work.

hope it might help